# how to connect to mongodb from express?

Tags: mongodb, express, mern

*Tried to connect To mongodb, it says connection not found.  can someone point out what error I have made in code, is there any problem in db connect URI*

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

const db =
  "mongodb+srv://<sumit>:<sumit>@bike-ecommerce.u7sod.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

console.log(db);
mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connection successful");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use(express.json());

//importing routes

const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

//route middle wares
app.use("/api/user", authRoute);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("gg server is running"));
```

Comment: .then is missing an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a snippet from my own application it works there

```
mongoose.connect(dbUrl).then((dbo)=>{
  console.log("DB connected")
},(err)=>{
  console.log("error")
});
```

I have connected like this your then is missing a variable tell me if this dosnt work

Comment: Is there any problem in uri, its demo database so i am sharing full link.  The code is working, at the end it's throwing atlas error.

Comment: I tried connecting through studio 3t too its throwing same error

Comment: Follow this video hope it clears stuff up https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=68Jd7GXZPe8

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6SVnmqhcAek

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution.
Thanks for the help *@ahmed ali*.

In db uri, username and password should be written without angular brackets and replace the first database with your database name created.

Comment: No probs Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Write down the username and password example:

```
monggoose.connect('mongodb+srv://name:password@cluster0.cjjucgj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
```